# onSubmit triggers on every change, basic form did not

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react, semantic-ui-redux-form-fields

I'm converting a project to use Semantic-UI-React and a form is triggering on every change. The old form looked like this and worked as intended:

```
<div className="entryForm">      
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> 
                <span className="formLabel">Location:</span>
                <input type='text' name="location" placeholder="Location" 
                   onChange={this.handleChange} autoComplete="off" /><br/>
                Date Activity:
                <input type='text' name="activity" placeholder="Activity" 
                   onChange={this.handleChange} autoComplete="off"/><br/>
                Cuisine:
                <input type='text' name="cuisine" placeholder="Cuisine" 
                   onChange={this.handleChange} autoComplete="off"/>
                   <button type="submit" value="submit" hidden="hidden"/>
              </form></div>
```

---

The Semantic form looks like this and displays both SUBMIT and HELP on every change in the form:

```
<Form onSubmit={console.log("SUBMIT")}
            onChange={console.log("HELP")}>

                <Form.Field inline>
                        <label>Location:</label>
                    <Input name='location' 
                           placeholder='Enter a neighborhood here' 
                           onChange={this.handleChange} 
                           autoComplete="off"/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field inline>
                        <label>Activity:</label>
                    <Input name='activity' 
                           placeholder='Enter a a fun activity' 
                           onChange={this.handleChange} 
                           autoComplete="off"/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field inline>
                        <label>Cuisine:</label>
                    <Input name='cuisine' 
                           placeholder='What do you want to eat' 
                           onChange={this.handleChange} 
                           autoComplete="off"/>
                </Form.Field>
            </Form>
```

What's going on?

Comment: Should I not include that the Semantic-React-UI in title @Rob? Basic HTML form was working, the change to sru is providing the problem

Comment: It should be `onSubmit(() => console.log("SUBMIT"))`. Same thing for `onChange`.

Comment: @SILENT, that and adding a hidden submit button did it, thank you

Comment: Word as you wish, just don't put tags in your title!

Answer (score 0):

`onSubmit={(() => console.log("SUBMIT"))}`

That fixed it as well as adding a submit button got it working